# Is this plot a ParetoFront? and What is the best plot for Pareto Front with >=3 objectives?

Tags: optimization, plot, evolutionary-algorithm, pareto-chart

I've plotted a Pareto Front (in RED colour) from my NSGA2 Algorithm execution and the result is this for Cost(Y)/Time(X):

[image]

> In X-Axis: Time in Days In Y-Axis: Cost in Euro

The problem has 3 objectives: **time**, **cost**, **environmental cost**.

*Are the gaps in the plot due to multivariable objectives (+3 objectives) in 2D plot ?*

*Could I plot everything in a 3D plot for a correct visualisation of the Pareto Front?*

*What is the correct visualization of a multivariable optimization (>3 objectives) for the pareto front?* In pairs? Everithing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you make this? did you use ggplot2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you have only two objectives (bi-objective problem), you can visualize the *Pareto* front in the objective plane and it is called trade-off curve.

For more than two objectives, techniques developed in statistics such as various diagrams could be used. The other way is to display the bi-objective cross-sections of the *Pareto* front.

In case, the above mentioned methods do not work efficiently you can use [Interactive Decision Maps (IDM) technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Decision_Maps)

I suggest, you first try to plot a 3D *Pareto* front and check it out. If it comes out not to be informative enough you can then try other methods. The second method I would try is to plot each couple of objectives as a single plot so for a problem including 3 objectives you need 3 different plots.