# Draw Pareto Front Line in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, optimization, pareto-chart, pareto-optimality

I have my results from multi-objective optimization problem in excel file. I use seaborn to plot my data. However, I want to plot a Pareto Front Line.

I am trying to plot my data similar to the figure this post ([Is this plot a ParetoFront? and What is the best plot for Pareto Front with >=3 objectives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426209/is-this-plot-a-paretofront-and-what-is-the-best-plot-for-pareto-front-with-3)). Any idea, thanks?

Here is my code but it only scatter plot my data.

My code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('file path')
sns.scatterplot('fun1', 'fun2', data=df, hue='alpha', legend=False)
plt.xlabel('fun1', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('fun2', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```